# How to exclude specific dimension result using Google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

How do I filter out (not set) from the query so that it doesn't display?

```
var mainChart2 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
              'dimensions': 'ga:socialNetwork',
              'metrics': 'ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:sessions,ga:newUsers',
              'max-results': '5',
              'start-date': '30daysAgo',
              'end-date': 'yesterday',
              sort: '-ga:sessions'
          },
          chart: {
              type: 'TABLE',
              container: 'main-chart-2-container',
              options: {
                  width: '100%'
              }
          }
      });
```

The current result I get is:

```
Social Network        Pages / Sessions        Sessions        New Users
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
(not set)             #                       #               #
Facebook              #                       #               #
Twitter               #                       #               #
```

The result I want is:

```
Social Network        Pages / Sessions        Sessions        New Users
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
Facebook              #                       #               #
Twitter               #                       #               #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) parameter of API to exclude dimension value using `!=` operator.

So you will have to add one key, value to the `query` object like this.

`filters: 'ga:socialNetwork!=(not set)'`